# mongodb shell command to spring data date range result

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I'am trying to get all the data using a date. I have executed this script in mongo shell and I get the desired data.

```
db.getCollection('table').find({

    Start: {
        $gte: ISODate("2016-03-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2016-03-14T01:00:00.000Z")
    }
    })


        TypedAggregation<PlayerStatistics> agg = newAggregation(PlayerStatistics.class,
                        match(Criteria.where("Start").
    gte(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(startDate))).
lt(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(endDate)))
                                ),
                    );
```

this is the coded generated by the spring-data

```
{ "aggregate" : "__collection__" , "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "Start" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2016-03-14T00:00:00.000Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2016-11-14T01:00:00.000Z"}}}}]}
```

Comment: What do you intend to `$sum`? It does by nature imply a `$group` pipeline stage, but you don't actually say what it is you want to "sum". Do you just want the count? Why not just use `.count()` on the cursor from `.find()` ?

Comment: from the mongodb shell. I get the desired output, but when translated to spring-data the result doesnt seem to match. There is a filed let say "visitors" I would like to sum all the visitors from the date range. But if I group it by "Start" field. It will separate the sum depending on the time retrieved in the database right?

Comment: Your question title and content could do with some work, since your real problem is you get different results from the match, correct? Chances are you are getting "Local" timezone dates as input rather than creating instances for UTC. As for grouping, it seems out of context for the question you are trying to ask about the problem you actually have. Best tackle one problem at a time.